# How to search a list in C# for a set ID

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.ios

I am building an app in Xamarin.Forms which has bluetooth functionality. After I have connected to a device, I have an `ObsevableCollection` which collects the available Services. I then want to select the service I am looking for.

The uses the [`Monkey.Robotics`](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/tree/master/Getting%20Started/Mobile_Stack) plugin, and is based on the sample [HeartRate Monitor](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/BluetoothHeartRateMonitor/) App. At the moment, there is a

```
this.services = new ObservableCollection<IService> ();
listView.ItemsSource = services;

// when device is connected
adapter.DeviceConnected += (s, e) => {
    device = e.Device; 

    // when services are discovered
    device.ServicesDiscovered += (object se, EventArgs ea) => {

        if (services.Count == 0)  //if it's only just started
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                foreach (var service in device.Services) {
                    services.Add(service); //add all new services found to ObservableCollection
                }
            });
    };

    // start looking for services
    device.DiscoverServices ();

};
```

So the current code retrieves all services and puts them into an `ObservableCollection`, which then populates a list view. Rather than populating a list and waiting for a user input, I want to search the results for the service I want. i.e.

```
await Task.Delay (5000); // wait 5 seconds for the scan to complete
IService ChosenService = null;

try {
        foreach(var data in services)
        {
            if (data!=null && data.ID!=null && data.ID.ToString() == 0x180D.ToString()){ ChosenService = data; break; }

        }
    }
    catch {

            Debug.WriteLine ("Exception");
    } 
    Debug.WriteLineIf(ChosenService == null, "Not Chosen");
```

## Third Update:

I have added the try, catch block as show above and also added the checks to make sure we aren't working with null references. This all compiles, and the app doesn't crash at any point! However, the process ends with  ChosenService = null? So this code isn't working. Any Ideas why not? The Service scan seems to be working, as in the debug window, I get the following feedback:

```
2015-09-26 22:09:38.329 Gas_SenseiOS[1431:605554] Device.Discovered Service: <CBService: 0x12832e7e0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Heart Rate>
2015-09-26 22:09:38.333 Gas_SenseiOS[1431:605554] Device.Discovered Service: <CBService: 0x12831c950, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>
2015-09-26 22:09:38.349 Gas_SenseiOS[1431:605554] Device.Discovered Service: <CBService: 0x12832e7e0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Heart Rate>
2015-09-26 22:09:38.350 Gas_SenseiOS[1431:605554] Device.Discovered Service: <CBService: 0x12831c950, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>
2015-09-26 22:09:38.352 Gas_SenseiOS[1431:605554] Device.Discovered Service: <CBService: 0x12832e7e0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Heart Rate>
2015-09-26 22:09:38.352 Gas_SenseiOS[1431:605554] Device.Discovered Service: <CBService: 0x12831c950, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Device Information>
```

Comment: is there any exception? try wrap code with `try-catch` block and see.

Comment: Always report the error/exception messages and where it happens.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I am debugging on my iPhone, as I need bluetooth and I am not getting any error message thrown. Not sure if it is a debugger error, or an app error?

Comment: are you sure the foreach is causing the crash?  Have you tried commenting it out?  What does the stack trace say?

Comment: @Jason The issue only appeared when I put this stage of the code in, however, I have just updated the question with the debug info, which would suggest it might not be?

Comment: I would try commenting out blocks of code until you narrow it down to a specific line that is causing the problem.  The fact that the try/catch isn't catching a null reference makes me think that isn't the source.

Comment: @Jason, Please see my update to the question, this has much more info now - you're right!

Comment: it may be as simple as `data.ID.ToString() == 0x180D.ToString()` not matching, either because the ID is not correct, or perhaps the case for the two strings is not matching?

Answer (score 1):

Shooting from the hip Id suspect you have a data element in your services that is null or has a null ID. 
try

```
if (data!=null && data.ID!=null && data.ID.ToString() == 0x180D.ToString()){ ChosenService = data; break; }
```

Comment: This line issues a warning - `The result of comparing value type 'system.guid' with null is always 'true'` - do we need the first check?

Answer (score 0):

Using all the comment above, and some research into the BLE specification and the way the plugin is written, the solution is to:

```
            IService ChosenService = null;
            try {
                foreach(var data in services)
                {
                    if (data!=null && data.Name == "Heart Rate"){ ChosenService = data; }


                }
            }
            catch {

                Debug.WriteLine ("Exception");
            }
```